# Python - BeautifulSoup does not produce the same code

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new in python and I would like to web scrape some information in this website:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.leroymerlin.com.br/piso-ceramico-interno-madeira-esmaltado-borda-arredondada-reale-noce-61x61cm-rosagres_89371261'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
mydivs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "carousel"})
```

But mydivs is empty, but in the view-source there is this line.
Likewise:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Give me links that I do not see in view-source and do not give me some links that I see in view-source.
I thought it was a iframe issue, but I tried and I could not solve it.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that python is receiving a different web page because it's being redirected to https://www.leroymerlin.com.br/localizacao.

In order to arrive to the webpage you're scraping, you should set region cookie so you don't get redirected:

```py
page = requests.get(URL, cookies={'region': 'eyJpdiI6IlN1SUhieDhmUGtxbDVzcHIyZVgrSUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZHhycHE0MGRlVWNkNHk0U2NDSCtCZz09IiwibWFjIjoiMmFiMjVhZTFjMjFhNWU4NzkyZmFiNTUxOGM5MWYzMmIzYmJiYzNkMDk4NDJjYWFiYTdkNDVjNjMzYzVjNWNhMCJ9'})
```

I'm using `eyJpdiI6IlN1SUhieDhmUGtxbDVzcHIyZVgrSUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZHhycHE0MGRlVWNkNHk0U2NDSCtCZz09IiwibWFjIjoiMmFiMjVhZTFjMjFhNWU4NzkyZmFiNTUxOGM5MWYzMmIzYmJiYzNkMDk4NDJjYWFiYTdkNDVjNjMzYzVjNWNhMCJ9` as region cookie, you can check the one you're using looking at the packets from your web browser development console
[image]

And this is the response:

```py
>>> mydivs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "carousel"})
>>> mydivs
[<div class="carousel" data-carousel-tracking-value="89371261" data-items='[{"alt":"Piso Cer\u00e2mico Interno Madeira Esmaltado Borda Arredondada Reale Noce 61x61cm Rosagr\u00eas","url":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_c1d5_600x600.jpeg","zoomDimensions":"1800","zoomUrl":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_c1d5_1800x1800.jpeg","shouldLoadImageZoom":true,"thumb":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_c1d5_52x52.jpeg","youtubeId":""},{"alt":"Piso Cer\u00e2mico Esmaltado Borda Arredondada 61x61cm modelo Reale Noce Rosagr\u00eas","url":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_esmaltado_brilhante_61x61cm_modelo_reale_noce_rosagres_89371261_ed4d_600x600.jpg","zoomDimensions":"600","zoomUrl":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_esmaltado_brilhante_61x61cm_modelo_reale_noce_rosagres_89371261_ed4d_600x600.jpg","shouldLoadImageZoom":true,"thumb":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_esmaltado_brilhante_61x61cm_modelo_reale_noce_rosagres_89371261_ed4d_52x52.jpg","youtubeId":""},{"alt":"Piso Cer\u00e2mico Interno Madeira Esmaltado Borda Arredondada Reale Noce 61x61cm Rosagr\u00eas","url":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_4550_600x600.jpeg","zoomDimensions":"1800","zoomUrl":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_4550_1800x1800.jpeg","shouldLoadImageZoom":true,"thumb":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_4550_52x52.jpeg","youtubeId":null},{"alt":"Piso Cer\u00e2mico Interno Madeira Esmaltado Borda Arredondada Reale Noce 61x61cm Rosagr\u00eas","url":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_586b_600x600.jpeg","zoomDimensions":"1800","zoomUrl":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_586b_1800x1800.jpeg","shouldLoadImageZoom":true,"thumb":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_586b_52x52.jpeg","youtubeId":null},{"alt":"Piso Cer\u00e2mico Interno Madeira Esmaltado Borda Arredondada Reale Noce 61x61cm Rosagr\u00eas","url":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_51ba_600x600.jpeg","zoomDimensions":"1800","zoomUrl":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_51ba_1800x1800.jpeg","shouldLoadImageZoom":true,"thumb":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_51ba_52x52.jpeg","youtubeId":null},{"alt":"Piso Cer\u00e2mico Interno Madeira Esmaltado Borda Arredondada Reale Noce 61x61cm Rosagr\u00eas","url":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_a684_600x600.jpeg","zoomDimensions":"1800","zoomUrl":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_a684_1800x1800.jpeg","shouldLoadImageZoom":true,"thumb":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_a684_52x52.jpeg","youtubeId":null},{"alt":"Piso Cer\u00e2mico Interno Madeira Esmaltado Borda Arredondada Reale Noce 61x61cm Rosagr\u00eas","url":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_09b7_600x600.jpeg","zoomDimensions":"1800","zoomUrl":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_09b7_1800x1800.jpeg","shouldLoadImageZoom":true,"thumb":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_09b7_52x52.jpeg","youtubeId":null},{"alt":"Piso Cer\u00e2mico Interno Madeira Esmaltado Borda Arredondada Reale Noce 61x61cm Rosagr\u00eas","url":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_8e45_600x600.jpeg","zoomDimensions":"1800","zoomUrl":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_8e45_1800x1800.jpeg","shouldLoadImageZoom":true,"thumb":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_8e45_52x52.jpeg","youtubeId":null},{"alt":"Piso Cer\u00e2mico Brilhante Borda Arredondado Reale Noce 61x61cm Rosagr\u00eas","url":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_borda_arredondado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_0001_600x600.jpg","zoomDimensions":"600","zoomUrl":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_borda_arredondado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_0001_600x600.jpg","shouldLoadImageZoom":true,"thumb":"https:\/\/cdn.leroymerlin.com.br\/products\/piso_ceramico_borda_arredondado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_0001_52x52.jpg","youtubeId":null}]' data-product-images-carousel="" data-sketchfab-id="7a24a14dabc44227b465d49673d144e4" data-sketchfab-placeholder="https://cdn.leroymerlin.com.br/assets/images/sketchfab-placeholder.svg" data-sketchfab-thumb="https://cdn.leroymerlin.com.br/assets/images/sketchfab-3d-model.svg">
<div>
<picture>
<source media="(max-width: 768px)" srcset="https://cdn.leroymerlin.com.br/products/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_c1d5_220x220.jpeg"/>
<source media="(min-width: 769px)" srcset="https://cdn.leroymerlin.com.br/products/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_c1d5_300x300.jpeg"/>
<img alt="Piso Cerâmico Interno Madeira Esmaltado Borda Arredondada Reale Noce 61x61cm Rosagrês" class="image" src="https://cdn.leroymerlin.com.br/products/piso_ceramico_esmaltado_reale_noce_61x61cm_rosagres_89371261_c1d5_300x300.jpeg"/>
</picture>
</div>
</div>]
>>>
```

Comment: It worked! Just one more question: how did you suspect of that?

Comment: In first instance, I did a request with cURL and got redirected, then tried with my browser and it asked my nearest location so they could choose my nearest leroy. Selected some random location and then inspected the cookies so I could use that in python requests, skipping all the redirection proccess. Glad it worked, happy new year!